# Visual Studio Enterprise suscription & azure?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have a Visual Studio Enterprise suscription and they show me that i have 150$ credit on azure.
Is there anyway i can use some of the azure services through my suscription?
if yes how?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think the question is on-topic. It's not even about using the software (Visual Studio) commonly used by programmers.

Comment: As it stands now, this question is very broad and will most likely be closed. Here's what I would suggest you do: 1) Identify what kind of application you want to build using Azure (e.g. website, mobile app etc.). 2) Next identify what Azure Services you will be needing to build those applications (e.g. for website you would probably want to start with Azure WebApps). 3) Check out the pricing page for the services you will need and figure out what all you can get in $150 credit you're getting.

Comment: @GauravMantri please re-review the question as it is a specific question on Azure. My answer may provide added context. If you change your mind please consider upvoting the question.

Comment: @user202729 please see my answer to see how this question is relevant. If your opinion is changed please consider upvoting the question.

Comment: @aaronR....The question is definitely related to Azure but it is not a specific question. That's why I mentioned that this question is very broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may use Azure offerings using your monthly $150 credit.

The only thing that I have come across that I can not use it for is for SSL Certificates.

When you create a new Azure resource be sure to select your subscription that you have the credit on.

[image]

Please note the following from Microsoft.

> The monthly Azure credit for Visual Studio subscribers is for development and testing only and does not carry a financially-backed SLA. We reserve the right to suspend any instance (VM or cloud service) that runs continuously for more than 120 hours or if we determine that the instance is being used for production. We are making this capacity available to Visual Studio subscribers on a best efforts basis; there is no guarantee of capacity availability.

For up to date details on what you can use it on see this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/credit-for-visual-studio-subscribers/).